# WSO2 IoT Server - Device Owner in COPE scenario

Tags: android, wso2, wso2-iot

Which is the correct configuration in a COPE scenario?

- Define as Device Owner the System Services?

> org.wso2.iot.system.service/org.wso2.iot.system.service.ServiceDeviceAdminReceiver

- or the Agent?

> org.wso2.iot.agent/org.wso2.iot.agent.services.AgentDeviceAdminReceiver

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you point me to the documentation you are referring to?

Comment: I've found some old or not official post that refers to ServiceDeviceAdminReceiver as Device Owner:

https://wso2.com/library/articles/2016/07/article-advanced-handling-of-cope-android-devices-using-wso2-enterprise-mobility-manager/#set

Comment: When I'm trying to sincronize device, I've found this exception:

12-04 15:17:14.739 21192-21205/org.wso2.iot.system.service E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[SystemService]
                                                                             Process: org.wso2.iot.system.service, PID: 21192
                                                                             java.lang.SecurityException: Admin ComponentInfo{org.wso2.iot.system.service/org.wso2.iot.system.service.ServiceDeviceAdminReceiver} does not own the device

Then, the WSO2 IoT System Service STOP.

Answer (score 0):

It's the **org.wso2.iot.agent/org.wso2.iot.agent.services.AgentDeviceAdminReceiver** you need to define as the device owner. You can follow the below steps in order to Define IoT server agent as Device Owner.

[image]

Please refer to the following documentation for more information regarding this.

[WSO2 IoT Server 3.1.0 - Docuemntation | Device Ownership Application](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/Device+Ownership+Application)

Comment: Ok, but: what's about the COPE scenario?

https://wso2.com/library/articles/2016/07/article-advanced-handling-of-cope-android-devices-using-wso2-enterprise-mobility-manager/#set

Comment: When I'm trying to sincronize device, I've found this exception:

12-04 15:17:14.739 21192-21205/org.wso2.iot.system.service E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[SystemService]
                                                                             Process: org.wso2.iot.system.service, PID: 21192
                                                                             java.lang.SecurityException: Admin ComponentInfo{org.wso2.iot.system.service/org.wso2.iot.system.service.ServiceDeviceAdminReceiver} does not own the device

Then, the WSO2 IoT System Service STOP.

Comment: You need to follow the given instructions and install the android system app provided by wso2 in order to get the cope enrollment working. 
Please refer to : https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/Integrating+the+Android+System+Service+Application

Comment: I've followed this instruction. The only step that I've not could do is:


_signed via your device vendor_ 


I've create a certificate ad-hoc and sign both APK (System Services and Agent with it). Any idea?

Comment: You need to get the system application signed by you vendor or root the device and provide the system user privileges to the system application in order to archive the full functionality of COPE enrollment like firmware upgrade etc.